# Fixing an issue with a missing mysql.sock file on a mac?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, mamp

I am trying to set up a local installation of WordPress on my mac using MAMP. I have been searching for hours for a description of how to fix this error that I am getting when I try to open the phpMyAdmin tab from the MAMP start page:

> 2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
> The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> Unknown language: en-iso-8859-1.

Here is some info on what I have going on

- I am running OSX 10.8.4
- I have MAMP version 2.1.3 installed
- This version includes MySQL 5.5.9

I have seen people talking about using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install the stuff that my computer is for some reason missing, would that be of use by any chance?

Comment: firstly, is MAMP turned on and is the red light showing for MySQL and Apache?

Answer (score 0):

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Should be the default location for the mysql socket. To check where MAMP will create the socket you should consult

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
```

to check where MAMP is creating the socket. Perhaps there might be another location specified.